# how can we join two mpg files using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, join, ffmpeg, concatenation

how can we join two mpg files using ffmpeg? i have tried 
cat file1.mpg file2.mpg > output.mpg
But it shows cat is not a recognized internal or external command error. Please help

Answer (score 2):

mpg container can be simply concatenated w/o any transcoding. which platform? if you're on windows (taking into account your error message), you need to use:

```
copy file1.mpg /b + file2.mpg /b output.mpg /b
```

`/b` indicates binary files

Comment: Andy i also tried the same way but i found that the output file does not works properly.i converted the output.mpg to avi format using ffmpeg.Then output.mpg as well as avi both work on vlc but not on windows media player.In windows media player the content of last file concatenated does not appears

Comment: vlc and media player use different codecs, seems it's the problem, check which one is used by media player (GOM player usually uses the same DirectShow filters as media player and provides this info) and try another one

Comment: The question asks specifically for "with ffmpeg".  This is not an answer.